# Simplifying line length with pre-commit, flake8, black, isort, pylint, etc

Tags: python, flake8, pre-commit, pylintrc, isort

When using multiple tools that either check or format python files, is there a way to set line length once for all?

Currently I have:

`.flake8` file:

```
max-line-length = 120
```

`.isort.cfg` file:

```
line-length = 120
```

`.black` file:

```
line-length = 120
```

`.pylintrc` file:

```
max-line-length = 120
```

Comment: no, each tool uses their own setting

Comment: the answer is obvious in all of the tools' documentation -- "the question does not show any research effort"

Answer (score 5):

If you use [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/), it's possible to configure all the above in the [pyproject.toml](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/) file as a workaround.

For example, my project looks like this:

```
[tool.black]
line-length = 130
target-version = ['py310']
include = '\.pyi?$'
exclude = '''
/(
    \.git
| \.hg
| \.mypy_cache
| \.tox
| \.venv
| _build
| buck-out
| build
)/
'''

[tool.flake8]
max-line-length = 130
extend-ignore = ["D203", "E203", "E251", "E266", "E302", "E305", "E401", "E402", "E501", "F401", "F403", "W503"]
exclude = [".git", "__pycache__", "dist"]
max-complexity = 10

[tool.isort]
atomic = true
profile = "black"
line_length = 130
skip_gitignore = true
```

This is combined with a [.pre-commit-config.yaml](https://pre-commit.com/) file that kicks off each tool upon commits, respectively:

```yaml
fail_fast: true

repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/ambv/black
    rev: 22.10.0
    hooks:
    - id: black
  - repo: https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8
    rev: 3.9.2
    hooks:
    - id: flake8
  - repo: https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort
    rev: 5.10.1
    hooks:
    - id: isort
```

Haven't used the individual linters much outside of pre-commit hooks, but would think they behave the same way when run via `poetry shell` or `poetry run black --check --diff file_name.py` for instance.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to @pythoninthegrass 's answer:

A method I use frequently is generating project boilerplate code using [cookiecutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter), which allows for all instances to be templated using jinja syntax

### for example

`pyproject.toml`

```ini
[tool.black]
target-version = ["py39"]
line-length = {{ cookiecutter.line_length }}

[tool.isort]
py_version = 39
line_length = {{ cookiecutter.line_length }}
```

along with your `cookiecutter.json` file

```js
{
  "project_name": "python-project",
  "line_length": 88
}
```

### using your example

`.flake8` file:

```
max-line-length = {{ cookiecutter.line_length }}
```

`.isort.cfg` file:

```
line-length = {{ cookiecutter.line_length }}
```

`.black` file:

```
line-length = {{ cookiecutter.line_length }}
```

`.pylintrc` file:

```
max-line-length = {{ cookiecutter.line_length }}
```

### execution

- I setup a [simple repo](https://github.com/will-wright-eng/cookiecutter-configs.git) for quick execution

```bash
python3 -m pip install --user cookiecutter
git clone https://github.com/will-wright-eng/cookiecutter-configs.git
cd cookiecutter-configs/
cookiecutter project-cc-template --no-input
```

`directory structure`

```bash
$tree . -a
.
├── .gitignore
├── README.md
└── project-cc-template
    ├── cookiecutter.json
    └── {{ cookiecutter.project_slug }}
        ├── .black
        ├── .flake8
        ├── .isort.cfg
        ├── .pylintrc
        └── pyproject.toml
```

- [cookiecutter docs](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html)